# center the icons logo in the cicles?

Tags: html, css, icons, contacts, footer

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX2ay.png)# the code was perfect in CodePen, what i run in a firfox or chrome this problem appears. i fixed it in 'browser inspect" with "line-hight" but when i write the solution in VScode, nothing is solved. the code was perfect in CodePen, what i run in a firfox or chrome this problem appears. i fixed it in 'browser inspect" with "line-hight" but when i write the solution in VScode, nothing is solved.

```css
.card21 {
  grid-area: z;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.socials {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  display: contents;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 50%; // this makes sure there are two items per row
}

ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  color: #262626;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 3;
}

ul li a:hover .icon {
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li a:hover:before {
  top: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:before {
  background: #3b5999;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:before {
  background: #55acee;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:before {
  background: #0077b5;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) a:before {
  background: #dd4b39;
}
```

```html
<div class="box card21">
  <div class="socials">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icon"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter icon"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in icon"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google icon"></i></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram icon"></i></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance icon"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried again in browser inspect, it was fixed by adding { line:height: 2;}

ul li a:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #f00;
transition: .5s;
z-index: 2;
line-height: 2;
}

thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following code:

```
ul li a .icon {
     position: relative;
     color: #262626;
     transition: .5s;
     z-index: 3;
     line-height:80px;
}
```

- Here i changed the line-height to match the circle height. So, If you change the height of the circle to x change that here also. It will work perfectly. Or you can use SCSS and add this size as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```css
.card21 {
  grid-area: z;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.socials {
  width: 550px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul {
  display: contents;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 50%; // this makes sure there are two items per row
}

ul li a .icon {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25%;
  color: #262626;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 3;
}

ul li a:hover .icon {
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li a:hover:before {
  top: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a:before {
  background: #3b5999;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) a:before {
  background: #55acee;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) a:before {
  background: #0077b5;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) a:before {
  background: #dd4b39;
}
```

```html
<div class="box card21">
  <div class="socials">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f icon"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter icon"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in icon"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google icon"></i></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-telegram icon"></i></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance icon"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `place-content: center;` declaration with the `display: grid;`. This is a modern way to center your items in a container (with vertical and horizontal way). Check out this code:

```css
ul li a {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  /* Comment this declaration */
  /* display: block; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-basis: 50%; // this makes sure there are two items per row
  /* Try these declarations to center your items */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You will also need the `text-decoration: none;` declaration to remove the underline from your links.

`@Hitesh Vaghela's` solution is also a smart way to solve this problem.